# How to check if CharSequence contains a span of certain style?

Tags: android, kotlin, spannablestring

I have an editText and need to check if the selected text is of a certain style. For example:

```
fun isOfStyle(text: CharSequence, charStyle: StyleSpan){
...
}

fun doStuff(){
   if isOfStyle(selectedText(), StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)){
      ...
   }
}
```

What would be the proper way to check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to iterate over a spannable, so get your text as a spannable

```
val spannableString = editText.text.toString() as? SpannableStringBuilder
```

If your text is not convertible then that means spans has not been set so you probably want to validate `null` as well

```
fun isOfStyle(spannable: Spannable, charStyle: StyleSpan){
    spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length, StyleSpan::class.java).filter {
        it.style == charStyle.style
    }
    //do something with your finding

}
```

So the `getSpans` basically gets you all the span instance of the class, with that you can iterate over it and use something to match, in this case the `StyleSpan` has a `style` that is an id.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sorry to bother, but would you know how could I, after checking with the isOfStyle(spannable, charStyle) function, get that spannable with other function like getSpannable(charStyle)?

Comment: You have it there, is the `it` on the iterator

Comment: I've tried it and it shows me that they're not comparable for some reason

Comment: How would I  implement it in java? Please tell me...